# Multiple Domains, one SSL, Need a htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I am new to this SSL process. I host several domains on one GoDaddy server. One just got a SSL. I configured the htaccess file so that domain works for the SSL, but the other domains have security issues, so I need to add some code to keep them http instead of https. Here is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wisconsin.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Add a RewriteCond that checks the host name of the request ...

Comment: are they all https and you wanna keep only one and exclude others?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition to specify what URL it needs to be used on. You could do that by adding the line: (Thanks to @croises for his input on this)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?wisconsin\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wisconsin.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or you could use an `if directive`:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'winconsin.com'">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wisconsin.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</if>
```

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Just so I am clear, if I do this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'wisconsin.com'">
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wisconsin.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</if>
Only wisconsin.com will use the SSL, all other domains will not. Is that correct?

Comment: No, so if you use the `if directive` the HTTPs code would go inside it. I'll put it in as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works somewhat. I cleared the cache. If I type www.wisconsin.com I get https, if I type wisconsin.com, I get an error. The other domains get http, like they should. So what do I need to add so both wisconsin.com and www.wisconsin.com get https?

Comment: @Lag With optional `www.` change 2 RewriteCond to one `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?wisconsin\.com [NC]`

Comment: Thanks @croises I've not used that method before, but I tested it on mine and worked great. Learn something new everyday, even while answering lol.

Comment: @MarkBuehl try using the method that Croises suggested. So just add that `RewriteCond` above your first condition.

Comment: Well I was out all day, tried it just now:
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'winconsin.com'">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond to one RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?wisconsin\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wisconsin.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</if>

I added that like you suggested and now all domains do not work, I get 

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

So I guess I need to do some quick research. I cannot find where all the coding is defined for the htaccess

Comment: No, the first option does not require the if statements around it. Just add the new condition to your old ones.

Comment: See my edit. No use of the if statements in the first option, the second option is using the if statements. Don't combine them like you have done so.